# Ionic 4 Side Menu set active link on initial first navigation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I have a side menu in my app which works fine for showing the active link. My only problem is when I run the app initially, the active link is not highlighted. I subscribed to the `RouterConfigLoadEnd` event to set the selected link, but I don't think that's the right way because if I navigate to another link it will keep setting it. Any suggestions?

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  const initialPage = this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouteConfigLoadEnd) => {
    console.log('inital load');
    this.selectedPath = '/menu/forecast';
  });
  // Tried to unsub here but then the active link will not be active at start
  // initalPage.unsubscribe();
  this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    if (event && event.url) {
      console.log('set active');
      this.selectedPath = event.url;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to **NavigationEnd** Event of Router that triggers each time navigation to a page ends successfully.
[Official DOc](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd)

```
this.router.events.subscribe((events:NavigationEnd)=>
          {
            this.selectedPath = events.url;
          })
```